# Error while importing cv module in python

Tags: python, computer-vision

I've tried to import `cv` in python but I get this error:

```
undefined symbol: _ZN2cv17phaseCorrelateResERKNS_11_InputArrayES2_S2_Pd
```

I executed first this command:

```
export PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/:$PYTHONPATH"
```

then:

```
import cv
```

full Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv.py", line 1, in <module>
    from cv2.cv import *
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so: undefined symbol: _ZN2cv17phaseCorrelateResERKNS_11_InputArrayES2_S2_Pd
```

If I execute :

```
import cv2.cv
segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: please, tell us when you did get the error, it seems more like a c++ error other than anything else x=

Comment: Please include a *full* traceback. Your `PYTHONPATH` export looks redundant, unless you are using a Python not installed in `/usr/local/bin` but somewhere else.